# Can I retarget the chrono class to use microcontroller as tick generator?

Tags: c++, arm, c++-chrono

I want to use the timer in my microcontroller as tick generator of the chrono class.
imagine that I have function that gets the tick from timer register in the MCU and I call it get_tcik() and this register is 32 bit unsigned integer which increments each 1 microsecond.
Now to use it with chrono I've created a class like this:

```
class clock
{
public:
  static std::chrono::time_point<clock, std::chrono::duration<std::uint32_t, std::ratio<1, 1000000> now() {
    return std::chrono::time_point<clock, std::chrono::duration<std::uint32_t, std::ratio<1, 1000000> {std::chrono::duration<uint32_t, std::ratio<1, 1000000>> { get_tick() }};
}
};
```

And it doesn't work!

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work!"  You are experiencing some kind of problem, so please tell us what that problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because the chrono library detects suboptimal code formatting. :-)

Just kidding.

You're missing some nested types for `clock` that client code might expect to be there.  Also you can use `std::micro` in place of `std::ratio<1, 1000000>`.  Your choice isn't wrong.  This is just a stylistic suggestion.

```
#include <chrono>

class clock
{
public:
    using rep        = std::uint32_t;
    using period     = std::micro;
    using duration   = std::chrono::duration<rep, period>;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<clock>;
    static constexpr bool is_steady = true;

    static time_point now() {
        return time_point{duration { get_tick() }};
    }
};
```

Here's the official requirements: http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.req

Be advised that your clock will roll-over about every hour and 11 minutes.

Comment: Oh, that's much better. Thanks. I read the official requirements and noticed the is_steady is true if always t1 <= t2. But in my case it's not true, as you have mentioned it will roll-over (after 1.2 hours). So in my case, is_steady should be false. As for rolling-over, I know how to overcome the issue; instead of differentiating t2 - t1, I should check t1<t2 and if it's not, then use 0xFFFFFFFF - (t1 - t2) as the time difference.